# Little empty space at the border on iPhone 5 & 6

Tags: html, css

So if I visit the page https://viid.su/ on an iPhone 5/6 or use the inspect elemnt tool to visit it on an iPhone, it always has an empty space a the right border, going down the whole page!Also the Shorten button is one px to high than it should be (only on iPhones too).

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking in this question?

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text on the button in div id="fh5co-features-2 section is too long for the width of the viewport.

You need to either reduce the font or chop off some of this text: "Create without registration"